# Django CMS placeholder template

Tags: python-3.x, django-cms

Как вы добавляете placeholder в шаблон приложения? Сейчас объясню.

```
class WorkDetail(DetailView):
    model = models.Work
    template_name = 'page/work-detail.html'

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        if (self.request.toolbar):
            menu = self.request.toolbar.get_or_create_menu('work-menu', self.object.name)
            menu.add_modal_item(name = 'Редактировать работу', url = '/admin/work/work/%s/' % (self.object.id))
            menu.add_modal_item(name = 'Удалить работу', url = '/admin/work/work/%s/delete/' % (self.object.id))

        return super(WorkDetail, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
```

Мне в шаблон work-detail.html нужно как то добавить placeholder что-бы редактировать блок формы на странице, из админ-панели. Если кто сталкивался подскажите как реализовать.

Comment: Это есть в документации - [How to use placeholders outside the CMS](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/placeholders.html).

Comment: Я это уже читал, делал всё под документации, не появилось в интерфейсе ничего для редактирования заполнителя.

Comment: Невнимательно читали видать. У меня работает.

Comment: Вот перечитываю) И я не совсем понял нужно CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF в settings.py определять slotname чтобы заработало?

Comment: Нет, CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF вообще необязателен.

Comment: Странно. Вроде всё очень просто, сделал, не работает. Ну ладно буду пробовать)))